# DevOps Yaml pass output variable to template as parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to use output variables to pass values between stages. I create an output variable and populate it.

In the second stage I use the variable inside a script and it works as expected.

However, when I try to pass this into the template it doesn't work. How do I pass this value into the template?

```
stages:
  - stage: AllocateEnvironment
    jobs:
      - job: AllocateEnvironment
        steps:
          - script: |
              environment="test"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Environment;isOutput=true]$environment"

            name: AllocateEnvironment

  - stage: ScaleUpEnvironment
    dependsOn: AllocateEnvironment
    variables:
      Environment: $[stageDependencies.AllocateEnvironment.AllocateEnvironment.outputs['AllocateEnvironment.Environment']]
    jobs:
      - job: ScaleUpEnvironment
        displayName: 'Scale up environment'
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "Environment: $(Environment)"
          - template: scaler.yaml
            parameters:
              environment: $[stageDependencies.AllocateEnvironment.AllocateEnvironment.outputs['AllocateEnvironment.Environment']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the value of output variable on the steps in a different stage, you need to use the expression **`stageDependencies.STAGE.JOB.outputs['TASK.VARIABLE']`** to map the output variable as a general variable at a job level. Then on the steps of this job, you can directly call the general variable using the expression **`$(VarName)`** to pass the value.

For you case, there are two ways to pass the value of output variable to the step template. See below examples as reference.

##### 1. Directly call the general variable mapped for the output variable in the step template.

- Main YAML: `azure-pipelines.yml`

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: 'Job A1'
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Set Output Variable'
      name: setOutputVar
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outVar;isoutput=true]op1234"

- stage: B
  displayName: 'Stage B'
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    displayName: 'Job B1'
    variables:
      outVarFromA: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['setOutputVar.outVar'] ]
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Print outVarFromA'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo "outVarFromA = $(outVarFromA)"
    
    - template: Step-Templates/insert-step.yml
```

- Step template: `Step-Templates/insert-step.yml`

```yaml
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'A template step'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      echo "This is a template step."
      echo "outVarFromA = $(outVarFromA)"
```

- Result

[image]

##### 2. Pass the value from the general variable to a parameter in the step template. Just like as you are doing.

- Main YAML: `azure-pipelines.yml`

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: 'Job A1'
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Set Output Variable'
      name: setOutputVar
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outVar;isoutput=true]op1234"

- stage: B
  displayName: 'Stage B'
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    displayName: 'Job B1'
    variables:
      outVarFromA: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['setOutputVar.outVar'] ]
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Print outVarFromA'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo "outVarFromA = $(outVarFromA)"
    
    - template: Step-Templates/insert-step.yml
      parameters:
        MyVar: $(outVarFromA)
```

- Step template: `Step-Templates/insert-step.yml`

```yaml
parameters:
- name: MyVar
  type: string

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'A template step'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      echo "This is a template step."
      echo "MyVar = ${{ parameters.MyVar }}"
```

- Result

[image]

Comment: Option 2 was exactly what I was after. I tried a lot of different syntaxes along those lines, but obviously didn't quite get it right. Thanks!

Comment: Here your template contains steps, but what if you have a job template? :)